# Create Instance At RunTime

Tags: c#, reflection, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset, system.reflection

Following are the Classes in Namespace Files

```
 1. File01DataTable
 2. File02DataTable 
 3. File03DataTable
 4. File04DataTable
 5. File05DataTable
 6. File06DataTable
```

Now i want to create instance at runtime. If the file is File01 then the instance of File01DataTable should be created and so on.There shouldn't be any if else. Instead of following which is instantiating File01DataTable it should be common.

```
File01DataTable dt = (File01DataTable)tDS.Tables[filename];
```

I thought i can do it like this

```
string dataTableName = filename + "DataTable";
dataTableName dt = (dataTableName)tDS.Tables[filename];
```

But sorry to say this is not proper way. Here tDS is instance of Files or you may ignore it. Any advice? 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  **[Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)** method for getting instance of class from its name.

For example, in my application I have myClass class like that:

```
class myClass
{
    public string myField;
}
```

Then you can get instance of this class like that:

```
Type myType = Type.GetType("Your_app_namespace.class_name");  // for me FarhadApp.myClass
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
```